Mounts denied in Docker on Ubuntu
I am using docker-compose up -d --build to create an image of a django project on Ubuntu 20.04. I created Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. I was faced with an error while building it:
✔ Container postgres  Started                                              
⠙ Container app       Starting                                                                    
Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: 
The path /media/shokouh/51eb51ef-6583-499a-81b4-5f3f2e6acac2/codes/SmartFactorySystem is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.


I solved the problem by adding the path that I want to build an image in this bellow:
Docker Desktop > Resources > File sharing > /path/tp/exported/directory
